# How to not stop a Google Function after response (res.status)

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I programmed an asynchronous function which quickly respond to the http trigger and then continue working.

I face a blocking problem: Look like the function is stopped quickly after `res.status('200').send('Message')` is sent Oo.

For example:

```
exports.functionName = function functionName (req, res) {
  function_promise1(req)
    .then(function(){
      return function_promise2()
    })
    .then(function (response){
      res.status(200).send('Triggered !');
      function_promise3() //Won't be executed ! Or only for few ms.
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
      res.status(500).send(e.message);
    })
};
```

Are the Google function really stopped after response or I am missing something ?

Comment: Once you call "send", it's over. If you want a log message, you need to use logs, not http response. This is not just in cloud functions - this applies to all http responses.

Comment: Sounds like a great *answer* Andrei! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call "send", it's over. If you want a log message, you need to use logs, not http response. This is not just in cloud functions - this applies to all http responses.

Comment: I don't want to log a message @andrei-volgin, I would like this function to answer the request just to close the connection with the requester, and then perform actions after.

Comment: Example Scenario: 1. Function receives an http trigger 2. Function answer directly to say ok I will do my job 3. Function does its jobs

Comment: HTTP requests don't work that way. You can do the work and then respond. One option is to have two separate functions: A and B. Function A receives a request, starts function B, responds OK. Function B continues to work as long as necessary.

Comment: Yeah thank you for this proposition, after discussions we also arrived to this conclusion, to use two functions, I'm gonna try !

Comment: Remember that currently there is ~9 min limit on functions. You may also accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue. My solution is: 
- Create two api, one is first api client call in order to run a main function which need to run after send response. the second api is where main function actually will be called.

```
app.get("/voterefresh", async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  try {
    fetch("");
    return res.json({ message: "vote refresh script is started !" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ err });
  }
});

app.get("/script", async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  try {
    await main();
    return res.json({ message: "vote refresh script's done' !" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ err });
  }
});
```